# Sequential models and distribution shift in RL

Tags: deep-rl, long-short-term-memory

We know the problem of "distribution shift" in deep Reinforcement Learning, where the change in policy during training affects the behavior of the agent and therefore the distribution of the collected data. This can cause instability during training.
Since sequential models (like LSTM) generate their next input directly (at least partially), I was wondering if policies based on sequential models were even more sensitive to this phenomenon?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "policies based on sequential models"? By sequential models, do you mean based on RNNs?

Comment: Yes I mean policies like RNN, LSTM, GRU which would operate on sequence of observations. For instance:
h_t, a_t = LSTM(x_t, h_{t-1}).
Here the LSTM predicts the next action a_t but also predicts part of the next observation (h_t).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the distribution of trajectories that your agent will observe, which changes during training

LSTM at most might solve the "i.i.d." assumption, however doing a parallelism to NLP, it's like if at the beginning of the training, you train your model on Wikipedia, then at some point you switch to Reddit, after a while to Twitter and so on

Comment: Yeah but what I mean is that in some way, if the policy is an LSTM, the distribution of trajectories will be "even more" affected since some part of the input data is "directly" generated by the policy. I was wondering if this could be the cause of even greater instability.

Comment: @SuperTardigrade depends, if the LSTM sees that it only need the current observation (i.e. the Markov property holds for the environment), then it will learn to ignore the past